# What does '[24] could not open read-only' error mean while benchmarking QuestDB in docker?

Tags: questdb

I'm running the [time series benchmark suite](https://github.com/questdb/tsbs) against QuestDB in docker on Amazon Linux. The QuestDB image dies with an error like:

```sh
I i.q.c.l.t.LineTcpMeasurementScheduler could not create table [tableName=cpu, ex=could not open read-write
...
io.questdb.cairo.CairoException: [24] could not open read-only [file=/root/.questdb/db/cpu/service.k]
```

Is there something with permissions that needs to be cleaned up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `24` error, is `OSError: [Errno 24]` on the OS-level and this indicates the maximum number of open files has been hit. You can usually set this using `ulimit` when running from binaries or homebrew.

What you can do from docker is a `run` command and pass the ulimit flag like the following:

```sh
docker run --ulimit nofile=5000:5000 \
-p 9000:9000 -p 8812:8812 -p 9009:9009 \
questdb/questdb
```

For more info, see the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit) and the [questdb docs for maximum open files](https://questdb.io/docs/operations/capacity-planning/#maximum-open-files)